# How to access localizable images in bundle in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, uiimage

I have [custom bundle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5x6O.png) bundle. And my app supports 5 different languages, my problem is how to access localized image from bundle. Without using localization i can easily access like this

**[UIImage imageNamed:@"uiimages.bundle/someImage.png"]**,

but i need to access localized image from custom bundle.

Answer (score 0):

You should access localized resources in the appropriate bundle using the simple name

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"sample_check_back"]
```

Comment: But i added "uiimages.bundle" into my project, from bundle i need to access localizable image